# How to know what document is crashed on reopening?

Tags: objective-c, macos

For example, user opens 10 documents in my application.
On relaunch, application crash on reopening one of this 10 documents.
On the next launch user will get a message: "The last time you opened "ApplicationName", it unexpectedly quits...".

I need to handle on which document application is crashed, and notify user that, for example, "document10 cannot be reopened...", and reopen 9 documents.

Please help. I didn't find anything in Cocoa documentation about this.

And sorry for my English, it is my second language.

Answer (score 0):

While opening the documents, just save the current document URL in a user default, say `LastAttemptedOpenURL`, and then set it to null once the document has been opened. Then on launch, check for this key, and if it is not null assume that the document crashed the application.

Answer (score 0):

You have full control of the code that reads the data within the `NSDocument` class (for example the method `-readFromURL:ofType:error:outError`), so it sounds like you need more error-checking and possibly some exception handling in these methods:

```
- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL
             ofType:(NSString *)typeName
              error:(NSError **)outError {

    @try {
        // Do read
    } @catch(NSException *ex) {

        if (outError) {
            NSMutableDictionary *errorDetail = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [errorDetail setValue:@"Something bad happened"
                           forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyErrorDomain"
                                            code:100
                                        userInfo:errorDetail];
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Things are more complicated if you decide to do *async reading*, however it's still possible to avoid a crash in potentially dangerous areas.